# Qt 5.4/QML: How do I correctly implement a custom C++ class as a global QML singleton instance and implement code for its signals (in QML)?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have a little C++ class that I want to register with QML so I can access it from QML code and provide a safe API for the QML developer - while keeping the complex stuff "under the hood" and hidden from the perspective of QML.

So far I have written my custom class like this:

---

#### main.cpp

```
static QObject *myapi_singletontype_provider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
    MyApi *apiInstance = new MyApi();
    return apiInstance;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyApi>("com.example.myapi", 1, 0, "MyApi", myapi_singletontype_provider);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("http://server.com/myqml.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

#### MyApi.h

```
#ifndef MyApi_H
#define MyApi_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QObjectList>

class MyApi : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyApi(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyApi();


signals:
    void downloadStarted(const QString &uuid);
    void downloadFinished(const QString &uuid);
    void downloadError(const QString &uuid, const QString &errorText);
    void downloadProgress(const QString &uuid, const float progress);

public slots:
    void downloadArchiveInBackground(const QString &uuid);


};

#endif // MyApi_H
```

---

#### MyApi.cpp

```
#include "MyApi.h"

void MyApi::downloadArchiveInBackground(const QString &uuid) {
    // I would like to connect these signals to JS methods in QML!
    emit downloadStarted(uuid);
    emit downloadProgress(uuid, 0.3);
}
```

---

#### QML (pseudo)

```
MyApi {
    id: myapi
    onDownloadStarted: {
        console.log("OK STARTED")
        dialogDownload.open()
    }
}
```

---

Actually I have no idea how to implement this. I'm aware that I'm creating an instance here, and with Singletons that's not required since it's a singleton instance - but I need some pointers on how to implement the signal handlers in QML that I emit from C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Connection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html) QML type.

```
import com.example.myapi 1.0

Connections {
    target: MyApi
    onDownloadFinished: //do something
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Never seen `Connections` around, I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Awesome! Have some +1. ;)